# Add text along with image HTML

Tags: image, html, text

Hi i have a div like below

```
<div id="iconArrow"><img src="footer.jpg" width="35" height="27" style="position:fixed;"></div>
```

**i need to add a text "more" on right side of image. please help me  check the example image for final output.**

after adding codes
[image]

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with html5.

Comment: `position: fixed;`? Super Wrong

Comment: Psition fixed is for some other purpose and its working fine..i need a text on right side of image

Comment: What do you mean by text, is it a <p> <span> <div>, if so just position it with css, your question makes no sense the way it is right now.

Answer (score 1):

It could have something to do with HTML5.

**HTML5**

```
<figure>
  <img src="footer.jpg" width="35" height="27">
  <figcaption>More</figcaption>
</figure>
```

**CSS**

```
figure {
    position: fixed;
}
figure > * {
    float :left;
}
```

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mathijsflietstra/WEjbG/1/)</kbd>

Comment: i saw that one ..its working there but for me its not working should i add anything extraa?

Comment: It's HTML5, make sure to set your `doctype` to `<!DOCTYPE html>` and add [a HTML5 shim](https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/) for older browser support. Then it should work.

Comment: its shifting actually

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say with that last comment.

Comment: actually image is shifting check my images in question

Comment: Check if `div#iconArrow` has any styles applied to it, and apply those to `figure`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your image to be fixed and you want to add a text beside it I suggest your wrap your image tag in another div with fixed position and do this:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="position: fixed;width: 35px;height: 27px;">
    <img src="footer.jpg" width="35" height="27" /><div style="position: absolute;right: 0">your note</div>
</div>
```